# How to shift pandas column elements for matching observations across time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

Suppose we have the following dataframe:

```
    Date    Type    Country Value
0   2016-04-30  A   NL       1
1   2016-04-30  A   BE       2
2   2016-04-30  B   NL       3
3   2016-04-30  B   BE       4
4   2016-04-30  C   NL       5
5   2016-04-30  C   BE       6
6   2016-04-30  C   FR       7
7   2016-04-30  C   UK       8
8   2016-05-31  A   NL       9
9   2016-05-31  A   BE       10
10  2016-05-31  A   FR       11
11  2016-05-31  B   NL       12
12  2016-05-31  B   BE       13
13  2016-05-31  B   FR       14
14  2016-05-31  C   NL       15
15  2016-05-31  C   BE       16
16  2016-05-31  C   UK       17
17  2016-05-31  C   SL       18
18  2016-06-30  A   NL       19
19  2016-06-30  B   FR       20
20  2016-06-30  B   UK       21
21  2016-06-30  B   SL       22
22  2016-06-30  C   NL       23
23  2016-06-30  C   BE       24
```

Which can be computed with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2016-04-30','A','NL',1], ['2016-04-30','A', "BE" ,2], ['2016-04-30', 'B',  'NL',3], ['2016-04-30','B','BE',4], ['2016-04-30','C','NL',5], ['2016-04-30','C','BE',6],['2016-04-30','C','FR', 7], ['2016-04-30','C','UK',8], ['2016-05-31','A','NL',9], ['2016-05-31','A','BE',10], ['2016-05-31','A','FR',11], ['2016-05-31','B','NL',12], ['2016-05-31','B','BE',13], ['2016-05-31','B','FR',14], ['2016-05-31','C','NL',15], ['2016-05-31','C','BE',16], ['2016-05-31','C','UK',17], ['2016-05-31','C','SL',18], ['2016-06-30','A','NL',19], ['2016-06-30','B','FR',20], ['2016-06-30','B','UK',21], ['2016-06-30','B','SL',22], ['2016-06-30','C','NL',23], ['2016-06-30','C','BE',24]], columns=['Date','Type' ,'Country' ,'Value'])
```

I want to add an extra column 'ValueShifted', that basically shifts the observations across time. Hence, for instance for the observation 'Date: 2016-05-31, Type: B, Country: BE', I would want to set 'ValueShifted' to 4. In case the observation is not available in the previous period, I would want to set it to NaN.

I could do it brute force, but this is gonna take too much time for my actual dataset. Is there a way to do this efficiently?

Expected df:

```
    Date    Type    Country Value  ValueShifted
0   2016-04-30  A   NL       1       nan
1   2016-04-30  A   BE       2       nan
2   2016-04-30  B   NL       3       nan
3   2016-04-30  B   BE       4       nan
4   2016-04-30  C   NL       5       nan
5   2016-04-30  C   BE       6       nan
6   2016-04-30  C   FR       7       nan  
7   2016-04-30  C   UK       8       nan
8   2016-05-31  A   NL       9        1
9   2016-05-31  A   BE       10       2 
10  2016-05-31  A   FR       11       nan
11  2016-05-31  B   NL       12       3 
12  2016-05-31  B   BE       13       4
13  2016-05-31  B   FR       14       nan 
14  2016-05-31  C   NL       15       5 
15  2016-05-31  C   BE       16       6
16  2016-05-31  C   UK       17       8 
17  2016-05-31  C   SL       18       nan 
18  2016-06-30  A   NL       19       9
19  2016-06-30  B   FR       20       14 
20  2016-06-30  B   UK       21       nan
21  2016-06-30  B   SL       22       nan 
22  2016-06-30  C   NL       23       15 
23  2016-06-30  C   BE       24       16
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want [`GroupBy.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
#df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
#df=df.sort_values(['Date','Type']) #order if necessary        
df['ValueShifted']=df.groupby(['Type','Country'])['Value'].shift()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
         Date Type Country  Value  ValueShifted
0  2016-04-30    A      NL      1           NaN
1  2016-04-30    A      BE      2           NaN
2  2016-04-30    B      NL      3           NaN
3  2016-04-30    B      BE      4           NaN
4  2016-04-30    C      NL      5           NaN
5  2016-04-30    C      BE      6           NaN
6  2016-04-30    C      FR      7           NaN
7  2016-04-30    C      UK      8           NaN
8  2016-05-31    A      NL      9           1.0
9  2016-05-31    A      BE     10           2.0
10 2016-05-31    A      FR     11           NaN
11 2016-05-31    B      NL     12           3.0
12 2016-05-31    B      BE     13           4.0
13 2016-05-31    B      FR     14           NaN
14 2016-05-31    C      NL     15           5.0
15 2016-05-31    C      BE     16           6.0
16 2016-05-31    C      UK     17           8.0
17 2016-05-31    C      SL     18           NaN
18 2016-06-30    A      NL     19           9.0
19 2016-06-30    B      FR     20          14.0
20 2016-06-30    B      UK     21           NaN
21 2016-06-30    B      SL     22           NaN
22 2016-06-30    C      NL     23          15.0
23 2016-06-30    C      BE     24          16.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's the possibility of missing observations, the safest way is copy the DataFrame, manually change the date, then you can exact merge.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df2 = df.copy()
df2['Date'] = df2['Date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Value': 'ValueShifted'})

df = df.merge(df2, on=['Date', 'Type', 'Country'], how='left')
```

---

```
         Date Type Country  Value  ValueShifted
0  2016-04-30    A      NL      1           NaN
1  2016-04-30    A      BE      2           NaN
2  2016-04-30    B      NL      3           NaN
3  2016-04-30    B      BE      4           NaN
4  2016-04-30    C      NL      5           NaN
5  2016-04-30    C      BE      6           NaN
6  2016-04-30    C      FR      7           NaN
7  2016-04-30    C      UK      8           NaN
8  2016-05-31    A      NL      9           1.0
9  2016-05-31    A      BE     10           2.0
10 2016-05-31    A      FR     11           NaN
11 2016-05-31    B      NL     12           3.0
12 2016-05-31    B      BE     13           4.0
13 2016-05-31    B      FR     14           NaN
14 2016-05-31    C      NL     15           5.0
15 2016-05-31    C      BE     16           6.0
16 2016-05-31    C      UK     17           8.0
17 2016-05-31    C      SL     18           NaN
18 2016-06-30    A      NL     19           9.0
19 2016-06-30    B      FR     20          14.0
20 2016-06-30    B      UK     21           NaN
21 2016-06-30    B      SL     22           NaN
22 2016-06-30    C      NL     23          15.0
23 2016-06-30    C      BE     24          16.0
```